# Shortcut to jump back to last location

Tags: phpstorm

Often then I code I press on methods to check them out. Obviously PhpStorm jumps to that method location. Is there a shortcut to jump back to where I was before pressing on a method? I don't want to scroll back to that certain part of code again.

Using Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>

Will take you to last location. If you use <kbd>Right</kbd> you can go the other way around.

Comment: For some reasons it doesn't work. What is the name of this binding in  keymap?

Comment: As simple as: `Navigate | Back`, `Navigate | Forward` or even `Navigate | Last Edit Location` -- see what keys are assigned there on your OS/your keymap.